# Using just Terraform scripts, how can I reuse an existing AWS Route53 zone record

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

Is there a way to get around the fact that there is not no `data` object defined for an `aws_route53_record`?

I am using the **AWS Parameters Manager** to store the object ID's of the resources that I want to share across different projects. In a *static* Terraform project, I create the shared resources, and then I save the *magic* ID's of the shared resources to the  **AWS Parameters Manager**.

Then, in each of the sharing projects, I use `data` objects to retrieve the AWS parameter values, and then I pull in the shared AWS resources.

Essentially, using just Terraform, I am trying to do the equivalent of the following:

```
terraform import module.networking.aws_route53_zone.example_dom EXAMPLEZONEID
terraform import module.networking.aws_route53_record.myproject_example_dom EXAMPLEZONEID_myproject.example.dom_A
```

Ideally, I would like to do the following

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "route53_zone_example" { name = local.route53_zone_example_ssm_lookup }
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "route53_zone_record_myproject" { name = local.route53_zone_record_myproject_ssm_lookup }

data "aws_route53_zone" "example_dom" { zone_id = data.aws_ssm_parameter.route53_zone_example.value }
data "aws_route53_record" "myproject_example_dom" { id = data.route53_zone_record_myproject.value }
```

Unfortunately, that produces the expected response

```
The provider hashicorp/aws does not support data source "aws_route53_record".
```

Again, what I am looking for a pure Terraform solution, one that does not require that I copy the resource definitions to each of the sharing projects.

Comment: Instead of querying the AWS route53 API, could you just do a DNS lookup instead? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest/docs/data-sources/dns_a_record_set

Comment: What *specifically* do you need to access on the `aws_route53_record`? If you just need the DNS address to pass into some other resource, why not just store it as a string?

Comment: The suggestion from Mark B to just store the DNS address as a string works well. It got me past the most obvious need, which is the DNS address that the DNS zone record points to.  Other than that, there really isn't much else that the DNS record has of interest.
@MarkB, if you add that as an answer, I will be glad to 'accept' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the DNS address to pass into some other resource, I suggest storing that as a string.